# Cant find the delete dumpstate/logcat on my Galaxy TXT (Y Pro, B5510)

Tags: internal-storage, insufficient-memory

My internal storage keeps running low, even though I keep removing apps, and I only have a handful of apps installed. I cant install updates anymore either for the ones I do have because of this. I read somewhere that i could try deleting the dumpstate/logcats by dialing *#9900# using the 2nd option: Delete dumpstate/logcat, but after dialing that number, this option is not showing up anywhere on the Sysdump list of my phone. Is there some other way to use this option?